# Display or filter only distint data from calculated column

Tags: powerbi

I have a datatable and from the data I calculate new calculated column. The calculation sums upp time for one of a system running per day.

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦══════════════════╗
║    date    ║ busyTime ║ systemBusyPerDay ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 29/08/2019 ║        2 ║               10 ║
║ 29/08/2019 ║        4 ║               10 ║
║ 29/08/2019 ║        1 ║               10 ║
║ 29/08/2019 ║        1 ║               10 ║
║ 29/08/2019 ║        2 ║               10 ║
║ 30/08/2019 ║        7 ║               15 ║
║ 30/08/2019 ║        1 ║               15 ║
║ 30/08/2019 ║        3 ║               15 ║
║ 30/08/2019 ║        4 ║               15 ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

The systemBusyPerDay is calculated using:

```
systemBusyPerDay = CALCULATE(SUM(Jobs[busy robot]), FILTER(Jobs, Jobs[StartTime].[Day] = EARLIER(Jobs[StartTime].[Day])))
```

When visualizing the result **I want to show the systemBusyPerDay value per each day only once**. I tried Filter or Distinct but didn't make it work.

The result I want to obtain is like this:

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦══════════════════╗
║    date    ║ busyTime ║ systemBusyPerDay ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 29/08/2019 ║        2 ║               10 ║
║ 29/08/2019 ║        4 ║                  ║
║ 29/08/2019 ║        1 ║                  ║
║ 29/08/2019 ║        1 ║                  ║
║ 29/08/2019 ║        2 ║                  ║
║ 30/08/2019 ║        7 ║               15 ║
║ 30/08/2019 ║        1 ║                  ║
║ 30/08/2019 ║        3 ║                  ║
║ 30/08/2019 ║        4 ║                  ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Please help :)

Comment: The details you provide not help much unless you share visualization and DAX of your calculated column. on wild guess you may think using IF Statement to show only once your calculated column value when busyTime = 1 (If that is the case for each date) ,something like IF(BusyTime = 1, Calculated Column, Blank())

Comment: Why not create a second visual with the date and the systemBusyPerDay? Then on your current visual you can take out the systemBusyPerDay column. Powerbi will keep al in sync, much easier for end user to understand..

Comment: @Aldert if I create such a viual, each entry in systemBusyPerDay will be plotted and therefore the thickness of the plotted column will depend on the number of entries per each day.

Comment: Not if you take out the busyTime column, then it shows only once.